# Subclassing multiple forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, subclassing

I have two forms like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField()

  def clean(self):
    print "Validating Person"

  def save(self):
    print "Saving Person"

def InstrumentForm(forms.Form):
  instrument = forms.CharField()

  def clean(self):
    print "Validating Instrument"

  def save(self):
    print "Saving Instrument"
```

I need to declare another form which subclasses both these forms. I'm using this method as an 
alternative to `FormWizard`.

```
def BandForm(PersonForm, InstrumentForm):

  def clean(self):
    print "Validating Band"

  def save(self):
    print "Saving Band"
```

Can I do this? When I call the validate on the `BandForm` I would like the validation first occur on the `PersonForm` and then on the `InstrumentForm`. When I call the `save` method of the `BandForm`, I would like first save the data in the `InstrumentForm` and then on the `BandForm`.

What I'm basically trying to do is to save data to both forms together. I was having trouble with `FormWizard` and thought that it might be possible to do it like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both forms inside one form tag (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms), then validate and save them in order you want, for example in view:

```
form1 = PersonForm(request.POST or None, prefix='person')
form2 = InstrumentForm(request.POST or None, prefix='instrument')

if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
  form2.save()
  form1.save()
  # return redirect
# render forms
```